# Is it possible to systematize the method behind Zagier's proof that $p = 4k+1$ is the sum of two squares?

Tags: number-theory

Zagier's proof (or perhaps the main idea should be attributed to Heath-Brown) works as follows:

- Consider the set $S := \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{N}^3 \; | \; x^2 + 4 y z = p \}$.
- $S$ has an involution $\sigma(x, y, z) = (x, z, y)$.
- A fixed point of $\sigma$ is a representation $p = x^2 + 4y^2$, so it suffices to show that $\sigma$ has a fixed point.
- An involution on a set of odd cardinality has a fixed point.
- If a set admits an involution with an odd number of fixed points, it has odd cardinality.
- Finally, Zagier exhibits an involution $\tau$ of $S$ with exactly one fixed point.

This method seems to have a great deal of potential, since, given an arbitrary diophantine equation, there are lots of ways we could see it as a specialization of another one.  Moreover, we can ignore trivial solutions easily by just changing the conditions on $S$.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a systematic way of exploiting this idea to prove that a diophantine equation has a solution?
2. Are there any obvious limits to the situations where such a technique could be applicable?

Comment: The problem in a genralized approach will be to find a nice way to express a solution of the given Diophantine as a fixed point of some simple involution in some larger set and also to come up with an unrelated involution that has exactly one fixed point. (Though we could also generalize to automorphisms of prime order $p$ and in the end such an aitomorphism with $1\ldots p-1$ fixed points)

Comment: I wondered if it was known (or "known") how well we expect this to work.  Given a particular diophantine equation it's easy to come up with ways of expressing solutions as fixed points of an automorphism of finite order, basically just by doing the same thing in Zagier's proof.  But then, given the new candidate equations to study, how many would we expect to have additional finite-order automorphisms?